# os.makedirs fails for unc paths in python

Tags: python, windows

```
import os

path = '\\\\?\\D:\\abcd\\687857\\MSSQL_DATA\\gfgf'
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path))
```

Note : Please make sure that the folder "abcd" doesnot exists.The error thrown is

```
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume 
label syntax is incorrect: u'\\\\'
```

Comment: The path is invalid. Try `mkdir` from the command prompt with that.

Comment: Use either `path = '\\\\?\\D:\\abcd\\687857\\MSSQL_DATA\\gfgf` or `path = r'\\?\D:\abcd\687857\MSSQL_DATA\gfgf'`. If it's Python 2, also make sure to decode `path` as a `unicode` string.

Comment: its not creating still

Comment: It should work, assuming you have access to create a directory in the root of drive D: and you used a unicode path. Does `os.makedirs(r'D:\abcd\687857\MSSQL_DATA')` work? Which version of Python are you using on which version of Windows?

Comment: it works for r'D:\abcd\687857\MSSQL_DATA' but not for uncpaths like  '\\\\?\\D:\\abcd\\687857\\MSSQL_DATA\\gfgf. python 2.7 windows 8 64 bit